# R identifying strings containing dash (-) and multi-digit numbers at the end

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset similar to the following:

```
identifier           number
cat-123              5
green-489743         25
orange-fish5         77
red-blue123          90
dog-23               34
orange5              17
reptile              9
purple-2             11
```

I am needing to create a new column "identifier_edited" that holds identifier in it, but without any endings that start with a dash and end in a number. This is what I'm needing the data to look like with that change:

```
identifier           number   identifier_edited
cat-123              5        cat
green-489743         25       green
orange-fish5         77       orange-fish5
red-blue123          90       red-blue123
dog-23               34       dog
orange5              17       orange5
reptile              9        reptile
purple-2             11       purple
```

Notice here how if the ending isn't a dash with a number (either multi-digit or single digit) then the same string is carried over.

I know how to identify a string ending in a digit and even a string ending in a single dash and a digit, but I don't know how to identify a string ending in a dash along with a single or multi-digit number.

Comment: try something with this regex, something like: `stringr::str_remove("-\\d+$")`, this removes the dash/minus sign (`-`), followed by any number of digits (`\\d+`) and the end of the string (`$`)

Comment: The key to the question is the "any or more" quantifier , (the plus sign (`+`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sub` with pattern `"-\\d+$"`

```
> setDT(df)[, identifier_edited := sub("-\\d+$", "", identifier)][]
     identifier number identifier_edited
1:      cat-123      5               cat
2: green-489743     25             green
3: orange-fish5     77      orange-fish5
4:  red-blue123     90       red-blue123
5:       dog-23     34               dog
6:      orange5     17           orange5
7:      reptile      9           reptile
8:     purple-2     11            purple
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(identifier = c("cat-123", "green-489743", "orange-fish5",
"red-blue123", "dog-23", "orange5", "reptile", "purple-2"), number = c(5L,
25L, 77L, 90L, 34L, 17L, 9L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify a string ending in a dash followed by a single or multi-digit number, Regex can be used.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {
    'identifier': ['cat-123','example-2 , 'example-3'],
    'number': [5,25,77,1,2,3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a regular expression pattern
pattern = r'-\d+$'

# Function to extract the edited identifier
def extract_identifier(identifier):
    if re.search(pattern, identifier):
        return re.sub(pattern, '', identifier)
    return identifier

# Apply the function to create the new column
df['identifier_edited'] = df['identifier'].apply(extract_identifier)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```